# Can I delete files in nginx client_body_temp directory?

Tags: nginx, inode

On my nginx server, I can't login to my wordpress site. The error log mentions " No space left on device".

> 2014/09/26 02:02:05 [crit] 1197#0: *32 open() "/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp/0030999742" failed (28: No space left on device)

There is space but I found that [my inode usage was 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage)

I have tracked down the ridiculous amount of files to `/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp` where there are too many files to count.

So my question is: what is this directory for, and can I delete these files?

Comment: Did you turn on `client_body_in_file_only` directive? Maybe those file was caused by that.

Comment: I didn't turn it on but it's on. Reading up on http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_in_file_only makes me think it's ok to delete them since it's optional to save them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what is this directory (/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp/) for?

The directory was used to save buffered temporary file from client request body. Normally the temporary file inside the directory was used to buffer request body that larger than `client_body_buffer_size`. And normally the file was removed after nginx has finished process the request.

Other use of that directory is to debug client request body. When you set `client_body_in_file_only on;`, [nginx will save the body to those directory](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_in_file_only). But, in this case nginx won't remove them. You can use `client_body_in_file_only clean;` for clean the temporal files or disable it with `client_body_in_file_only off;`

> and can I delete these files?

Yes, you can safely remove those files.